# Send Azure created workflow trigger URL after deployment to my application

Tags: azure

I have an Azure deploy button for a logic app with this template:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logic_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "logic_app_name",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('logic_app_name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        "manual": {
                            "type": "Request",
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "data": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Initialize_variables": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "variables": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "var-1",
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "value": {
                                            "alert_id": "@{triggerOutputs()['headers']['var-1']}"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "InitializeVariable"
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After deployment, access Logic app/ Logic app designer in the UI, I can get the trigger Http request URL which will use for sending data to that webhook.

My question is how can I make a callback request to my application (let say I have /azurecallback route) with created trigger URL as parameter after deployment so I can set it automatically?

Comment: could please help us with some brief what exactly you are trying to achieve? 
Are you looking how to pull the workflow url of the logic app using this arm template?

Comment: After deploy successfully, I want to make a request to my application from Azure with created workflow trigger URL as parameter so I can save the URL in my application. @VenkateshDodda-MT

Comment: Based on your requirement , instead of using `httprequest` trigger you can use recurrence trigger & Http action because once the deployment of workflow is done. you need to trigger another http request to perform callback. refer to the attached image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvIkW.png

Comment: Does it HTTP 2 always call after an amount of interval, I just want to set only 1 time (after deployment).